# URL call from magnific.css

Tags: css, joomla, magnific-popup

I use the dj-mediatools component on joomla 3.4.8.
I need to add a clickable button to magnific popup of the lightbox plugin.

I changed needed position and added needed button

css path:

```
 .mfp-counter {
background-image: url('/images/zakaz.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
line-height: 18px;
```

I tried to find the html file for this component and as I understand I can add an url link only to the java-script file

How can I create an url redirection for this class?

Comment: You should add your markup somewhere live.

Comment: Your questions are not really clear, anyway I'll give it a shot: the html rendered by the component is generated by a php file inside the component's tmpl folder of the view, something like ./components/com_dj_mediatools/views/_your_current_view_name_/tmpl, and in the backend's template manager you can create an override, which will be placed in /templates/your_template/html/com_djmediatools/viewname : that's the file you want to edit.

Comment: i dont have that location and that file: /html/com_djmediatools/viewname